# ViewPager doesn't finish when back button is pressed, it loads again

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've implemented a viewpager and it's working fine, but when use BACK button it doesn't get closed, and load again the viewpager using the default fragent, then if I press again back buton it finally get finished. Is the same behavior when I set Back Button like super.onBackPressed(); or get back fragment by fragment in viewpager. Hope you can help me. My code

Viewpager Activity

```
public class PerfilSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

private ViewPager mPager;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.viewpagerindicator);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();

    /*
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.

    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }*/
}

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Mi_perfil();

        case 1:
            return new Mi_porfil2();
        case 2:
            return new Mi_perfil3();    
        default: return new Mi_perfil();        

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

}

My xml slide

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

One of my 3 frgment used, the others is the same

```
public class Mi_perfil extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)      {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mi_perfil, container, false);

    return rootView;

}
}
```

Just to finish, I open the ViewPager activity from another Fragment from other activity using Intent:

```
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            spPerfiles = new SharedPreferenceSurveyTemp(getActivity());
            Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ScreenSlideActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: `but when use BACK button it doesn't get closed, and load again the viewpager using the default fragent, then if I press again back buton it finally get finished.` can you explain it more ?

Comment: @mmlooloo When i press BACK on my view pager it get finish(), but then the viewpager re-open again itself, then if i tried to finish again with BACK button the viewpager finally finish. I guess it's because I'm using OnTouchListener on my button instead OnClickListener just to open the viewpager.. I modified my  code

Answer (score 0):

You should put finish in:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ScreenSlideActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

If that doesn't work, try passing fragments with FragmentTransaction / FragmentManager.

Comment: thank you, but if I use finish(), it finish the last one activity and I want to "finish" the viewpager activity that is openned from this activity. ty

Comment: yea then you will have to deal with fragmenttransaction / fragmentmanager

Comment: It's not working, because I don't want to finish() the first activity, just the second, the viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was trying to use `OnTouchListener` to open a new activity inside a fragment. This is not the correct way to do it, and was causing my activity to get opened multiple times.

I fixed this by implementing an `OnClickListener` instead:

```
public boolean onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ScreenSlideActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```